# When does a View in a List get removed from the stack after it disappears from view?

Tags: swiftui

Given the following code:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var elements = Array(1...100)
    
    var body: some View {
        List(elements, id: \.self) { element in
            ElementView()
        }
    }
}
struct ElementView: View {
    let viewModel = ViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Row")
    }
}

class ViewModel {
    deinit {
        print("Deinit")
    }
}
```

When the list is scrolled to the end, `Deinit` is never printed indicating that all `ViewModel`s are in memory. If all `ViewModel`s are in memory then all `ElementView`s must still be on the stack as each one holds a reference to a `ViewModel`.

Can someone provide documentation on the lifecycle of a View inside List?

Comment: As I can see in your given code and in your question, you may missing some things in between, the class would never get terminated unless your app got killed by OS/User or when ever OS things can terminated your class while your app is alive(Termination of a class is under control of OS in standard coding). Also it make no benefit for you to create a new instance of class in each single element.

Comment: List creates some amount of views to present content and cache them (visible area + 1-2 at each side). You have same view type and it does not depend on any arguments, so once cache is filled all of them remain there, because in this specific scenario there is no sense to free/replace them.

Comment: The point of SwiftUI is to use structs instead of classes to prevent these kind of memory leaks. Why are you using view model objects in SwiftUI?